node.js bot is not playing sound
I have tried to make a simple discord bot to play music from youtube using ytdl and yt-search, but for some reason, after running the command to play the video, the bot connects to a channel, and is just... silent, no errors in the console, nothing, the bot returns the function.
Here's the code for the function, it's rather simple currently.
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("play a song from YouTube.")
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("search")
                .setDescription("Searches for a song and plays it")
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName("searchterms").setDescription("search keywords").setRequired(true)
                )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("playlist")
                .setDescription("Plays a playlist from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the playlist's url").setRequired(true))
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("song")
                .setDescription("Plays a single song from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the song's url").setRequired(true))
        ),
    execute: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
        // Defer the reply to ensure the interaction is acknowledged
        await interaction.deferReply();

        // Make sure the user is inside a voice channel
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) {
            return interaction.followUp("You need to be in a Voice Channel to play a song.");
        }

        // Create a play queue for the server
        const queue = await client.player.nodes.create(interaction.guild);

        // Wait until you are connected to the channel
        if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel);

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder();

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "song") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url");

            // Search for the song using the discord-player
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO
            });

            // Finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0) {
                return interaction.followUp("No results");
            }

            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0];
            await queue.addTrack(song);
            embed
                .setDescription(`**${song.title}** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}` });
        }
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "playlist") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url");
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST
            });

            if (result.tracks.length === 0) {
                return interaction.followUp(`No playlists found with ${url}`);
            }

            // Add the tracks to the queue
            const playlist = result.playlist;
            await queue.addTracks(result.tracks);
            embed
                .setDescription(`**${result.tracks.length} songs from ${playlist.title}** have been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(playlist.thumbnail);
        } 
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "search") {
            let searchTerms = interaction.options.getString("searchterms");
            const result = await client.player.search(searchTerms, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            });

            // Finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0) {
                return interaction.followUp("No results");
            }

            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0];
            await queue.addTrack(song);
            embed
                .setDescription(`**${song.title}** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}` });
        }

        // Play the song
        if (!queue.playing && queue.tracks.length > 0) {
            // Start playing the first track in the queue
            await queue.play(queue.tracks[0]);
            
        } else if (queue.tracks.length === 0) {
            // The queue is empty, handle this scenario appropriately
            console.log('The queue is empty.');
            return interaction.followUp('There are no songs in the queue to play.');
        }

        // Respond with the embed containing information about the player
        await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [embed]
        });
    },
};



I will appreciate any help!
I tried to do some debugging with console.error, and console.log, but... well, nothing of note came up.
